# How to create multiple executables within a single project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, executable, projects-and-solutions

Is it possible to have more than one executable for a single project?

My use case is the following:
I got a solution with plenty of projects in it, divided by roles (Business Entity, UI, Data Access, etc.) and I would like to have a project for the shell / console applications. I know I can create one project per console application, I know I could create a single console app that would accomplish more things, but for this once, I'd like to generate more than one .exe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just taught about it and one way to do what I want would be to generate .EXEs at runtime. The « console » project would generate a single « Deploy » executable which would, when called, compile the multiple .EXEs I wanted. Sure they are not generated at compile time and would require the execution of a kind of setup, but it would work.

I'll go with this solution for the time being, and I'll inspire myself of the snippet found at http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2378.htm.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 1-to-1 relationship between projects and generated assemblies.